# Как искать ошибки в коде Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Привет всем!
Я тут пытаюсь освоить Ruby on Rails и я не знаю как правильно искать ошибки. Если в PHP все было просто (или ошибку выводит компилятор, или смотришь что содержат переменные, что возвращает та или иная функция и тд.), но на RoR все не так уж и ясно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вы дебажите свой код.
Я установил Nginx и Thin, на которых и крутится мой RoR проект

Comment: А вы работали когда-нибудь с MVC фреймворками PHP? Фактически, они по структуре мало отличаются от ROR фреймворка. А так, почитайте о Unit тестировании.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

http://rusrails.ru/debugging-rails-applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первую очередь смотрю консоль (если в процессе разработки) или логи (если в работе).
Выводить переменные можно как в консоль (удобнее) так и в браузер (для отладки вьюх).

Выводить удобно вот этим гемом: https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

Собственно : http://www.rusrails.ru/debugging-rails-applications

Ещё здесь где-то было : http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/beginning

Добавлю примеров:

В Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'awesome_print'
end
```

В контроллере (результат в консоль):

```
def show
  @item = Model.find(id)
  ap @item #awesome_print
  puts @item #ruby standart
end
```

Вьюха (результат в браузер):

```
<%= ap(@item).html_safe %>
```

или

```
<%= debug @item %>
```

И Nginx с `thin` при разработке не нужны (иногда даже мешают). Достаточно rails s (webrick).

Answer (score 3):

Помимо уже данных ответов иногда полезно установить `gem 'pry'` в группу `:development` в `Gemfile` и ставить в коде, где необходима остановка `binding.pry`, так можно посмотреть не только то, что вы указали для печати из ответа [@mayar](/users/15414/mayar), но и что угодно. В этой точке кода в окне терминала появится привычный по виду `irb`, а выход из него с продолжением работы сервера - Ctrl-D.

Answer (score 0):

Так же полезен гем `byebug`. Он очень прост в использовании.

**Вот пример кода:**

```
def show
  byebug #место остановки дебага  
  @comments = @link.comments.order(id: :DESC)
end
```

В момент вызова метода `rails` приостановит роботу и можно проверить значение переменной в консоли.

**Пример использования:**

```
   9:   def show
   10:     byebug
=> 11:     @comments = @link.comments.order(id: :DESC)
   12:   end
   13: 
   14:   def new
   15:     @link = current_user.links.new
(byebug) @link
#<Link id: 1181, title: "Conatus adultus quod aliqua.", url: "http://monahanberge.biz/dorothy.blick", user_id: 22, created_at: "2017-02-13 21:44:15", updated_at: "2017-02-13 21:44:15">
(byebug)
```

Что бы выйти из режима дебага можно использовать команду `continue` или сокращенно  `с`, или команда перехода на новою строку в коде `next` или `n`.

Более подробная информация на странице в [github от разработчиков gem-а.](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)